# Does Acrobatics allow you to move at full speed through Difficult Terrain?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills

It seems to me like it should, but I don't think I've seen it stated plain and simple. What I have found is in [Acrobatics](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/skills/acrobatics.html#_acrobatics):

> You can keep your balance while traversing narrow or treacherous surfaces.

Is Difficult Terrain "treacherous"? Mh...

> You can use Acrobatics to move on narrow surfaces and uneven ground without falling.

Is Difficult Terrain "uneven ground"? Mh...

If I look at the Table:

> Surface Width: Greater than 3 feet wide => Base Acrobatics DC: 0*
>
> * No Acrobatics check is needed to move across these surfaces unless the modifiers to the surface (below) increase the DC to 10 or higher.

So let's look at the modifiers:

> Slightly obstructed (gravel, sand)    +2
>
> Severely obstructed (cavern, rubble)  +5
>
> Move at full speed on narrow or uneven surfaces   +5

Based on this, am I right to say that **one can make an Acrobatics check against DC 10 (severely obstructed + full speed) to move at full speed through difficult terrain?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Difficult Terrain is defined in the [Combat](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/combat.html) section as -

> Difficult Terrain
>
> Difficult terrain, such as heavy undergrowth, broken ground, or steep stairs, hampers movement.

So, I would say an Acrobatics check would enable you to move at full speed through SOME Difficult Terrain, but not all. On Broken Ground, or some sort of uneven shifting Difficult Terrain, yes, Acrobatics would help. But through Undergrowth or on Steep Stairs? I would say it would not help.

Alternatively, you could use an Acrobatics check to just jump over some Difficult Terrain, allowing you to potentially move at full speed.

Comment: Good point, distinguishing various types of difficult terrain. The jump solution is something I've had in mind too, though as a separate thing. Maybe combining both can be the solution I'm seeking.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are.

> First, you can use Acrobatics to move on narrow surfaces and uneven
>   ground without falling. A successful check allows you to move at half
>   speed across such surfaces—only one check is needed per round.

In an uneven ground you determine an appropriate  Acrobatics DC to move. If the check fails character can not move. If it fails by 5 or more the character falls prone. Check out [Grease](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/grease) spell for reference. If the check succeeds the character can move at half speed.

However by increasing the DC by 5 you can move at full speed. Check out the modifiers table [here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/acrobatics).

Comment: Uneven ground is not the same thing as Difficult Terrain. The OP is asking if you can avoid the rule of moving at half-speed through Difficult Terrain by using an Acrobatics check.

Comment: @YogoZuno I'd argue that all uneven ground is difficult terrain but not all difficult terrains are uneven ground, you're right on that. But if you check the examples he gave such as slightly obstucted +2 or severely obstructed +5, these very well fall under uneven ground category, in my opinion.